# Problems running with-react-intl example

Tags: next.js

I'm new to NextJS and I'm having problems running the `with-react-intl` example.

The example sets some more option for the dev script:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json server.ts",
...
  },
```

The command doesn't seem to work for me. When running the command I see the error:

```
> with-react-intl@1.0.0 dev /Users/.../Code/hr-tool/hr-next
> cross-env NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json server.ts

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960   throw err;   ^

Error: Cannot find module 'arg' Require stack:
- /Users/.../Code/hr-tool/hr-next/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../Code/hr-tool/hr-next/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js:9:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
    '/Users/.../Code/hr-tool/hr-next/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js' ] } npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! with-react-intl@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json server.ts` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the with-react-intl@1.0.0 dev script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     /Users/.../.npm/_logs/2020-10-07T17_07_50_776Z-debug.log
```

**I'm completely lost with this error, and can't seem to figure out what I need to get it running?**